# What happens when a memory allocating function is used as conditional statement

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-leaks

I have a function `foo` that returns a `char*`. In the body of the function I declare the `char*` variable, allocate it memory using `malloc()` and return it.

Now if I try to use the function foo as a conditional statement( e.g. `if (foo()) {  //code } )`, what happens to the memory allocated? What I am not able to understand is that when `foo()` is called, without assigning the return value to a variable, is the memory allocated in `foo()`, a memory leak?

I was able to execute the program when I called `foo()` but didn't assign the return value to a variable. But I am not able to figure out if the memory is really allocated in this case.

Comment: It is simply thrown away and causes a memory leak.

Comment: If the `code` in the function is executed memory allocation is successful.

Comment: Thanks. That does answer my question.

Comment: If you are on Linux try running such a program under valgrind. You can assign the value to a variable and do the null check in one assignment.  Maybe that was what you were trying to do?

Comment: I was analysing memory issues and came across this kind of usage in a number of libraries. I will definitely try what you have suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Is this for [tag:c] or [tag:c++]? There are superior ways of doing this in C++

Answer (score 3):

The comment succinctly answers your question.

> What I am not able to understand is that when foo is called, without
>   assigning the return value to a variable, is the memory allocated in
>   foo, a memory leak?

It is indeed a memory leak. You are allocating some memory and then forgetting the pointer to it.

On the other hand if you assigned the return value to a variable, using it you would have later freed the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to realise, and it's pointed out in the comments and in other answers, is that you're leaking memory.

```
char* foo()
{
    // Do things
    char* info = malloc;
    strcpy(info, "Hello");
    return info;
}

int main()
{
    if (foo())
    {
        std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The call to `foo()` is valid, and because it returns not a `nullptr` the condition is true; however, you've leaked the memory allocated by `foo()` as you've lost the pointer to it once `foo()` returns.

You can store the pointer in the same condition if you'd like:

```
if (char* f = foo())
{
    std::cout << "Success" std::endl;
    // Deallocate f
}
```

This will call `foo()`, assign the result to `f` and check for a valid pointer.

Otherwise, you can fix this by simply using `std::string` (or if you're using something that isn't a `char*`, you could just use `std::unique_ptr`):

```
std::string foo()
{
    // Do things
    std::string info = "Hello";
    return info;
}

int main()
{
    if (foo().length()) // does foo contain a valid string?
    {
        std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as the same as sample you see:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

you should design your function like this to alloc memory, you can using it everywhere without caring memory leak.

sample here. eg your code:

```
char* yourfunc() {
char *str;
str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);//only sample code
return str; 
}
```

bad code because when you malloc, you must using free function:free(str).
Improve code:

```
char* yourfunc(char* yourdes) {
     //do anything
    return yourdes; 
 }
```

using it:

```
char *abc;
abc = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5); //init here
yourfunc(abc);
free(abc); // free here
```